# GAE NDB: Calculating and displaying entity's view count efficiently

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, jinja2, app-engine-ndb, webapp2

I want to display the number of times an entity has been viewed directly on its template. For example, given this `Book ndb.Model`:

```
class Book(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty()
    view_count = ndb.IntegerProperty(default = 0)
```

It is handled by this:

```
class BookPage(MainHandler):
    def get(self, book_id):
        book = Book.get_by_id(int(book_id))
        self.render(book-page.html, book = book)
```

And here is the book-page.html:

```
<h2>{{book.title}} | {{book.view_count}}</h2>
```

One method is that we can set `view_count = view_count + 1`, and then `book.put()`, but this will involve a huge number of db writes.

There must be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counter information is persistent, you don't have another option than writing it to datastore.

For a more efficient and fast implementation i would invite you to check out [Sharding counters](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters)

Comment: Also note that simply adding without any locking protection will lead you to uncounted items. Transactions/and/or memcache can be used to svoid that.